# Disable all controls within Groupbox

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to disable all controls within `Groupbox` as shown below, but I am getting error On casting any suggestion ?

> unable to cast object of type system.windows.forms.checkbox to type
>   system.windows.forms.textbox

```
            foreach (Control cont in GB_Product_Entry.Controls)
            {
                if (cont is TextBox || cont is ComboBox)
                {
                    ((TextBox)cont).ReadOnly = true;
                    ((TextBox)cont).BackColor = SystemColors.Control;

                    ((ComboBox)cont).Enabled = false;
                    ((ComboBox)cont).BackColor = SystemColors.Control;

                    ((CheckBox)cont).Enabled = false;
                    //((CheckBox)cont).BackColor = SystemColors.Control;
                }
            }
```

Comment: change || to if else

Comment: If you want to disable all contols in `GroupBox` then you can disable `GroupBox` and all controls inside will be disabled.

Comment: @RomaDoskoch thanks

Comment: @LeiYang Thank you too

Comment: @sam, you are welcome

Comment: @sam why you are manually setting textbox to readonly state and changing backcolor? You can simply disable it and all will change automatically. And yes, use Roma's approach with disabling whole group at once

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy when I make `textboxs` read only using the foreach it will change the `textbox` to readonly but will not change the color of it .. any idea why ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why not just disable the GroupBox itself?

```
GB_Product_Entry.Enabled = false;
```

If you really must loop through them then separate the `if` conditions:

```
foreach (Control cont in GB_Product_Entry.Controls)
{
    if (cont is TextBox)
    {
        ((TextBox)cont).ReadOnly = true;
        ((TextBox)cont).BackColor = SystemColors.Control;
    }
    else if (cont is ComboBox)
    {
        ((ComboBox)cont).Enabled = false;
        ((ComboBox)cont).BackColor = SystemColors.Control;
    }
    else if (cont is CheckBox)
    {
        ((CheckBox)cont).Enabled = false;
      //((CheckBox)cont).BackColor = SystemColors.Control;
    }
    // Any other conditions here...
}
```

The issue is currently caused because inside the `if` statement you cast `cont` to `TextBox` and them moments later cast it to `ComboBox`. Well it can only be on or the other so the cast always fails at some point.

With the statements separated you know the type as it's filtered by the `if`.

Comment: @I was not know that disabling `GroupBox`  will disable all controls inside it.. I tried but the interface will look not really good since also labels ,will be disable too and the whole interface will show as it is inactive... thanks

Comment: @sam OK then use the if/else for each type.

Comment: @sam when you disable textboxes, comboboxes and checkboxes, then your interface SHOULD look as inactive to be clear for users. +1 for disabling whole group

Comment: @Equalsk I was wondering if I removed the `if-else statement` and just set the code does that will work out so i will not use `if-else statement` a lot ?

Comment: @sam stop and think for a minute why labels change their look when disabled. Label is not interactive control - you cannot enter some data into label. Labels change their look to notify user that control group is disabled.

Comment: @Equalsk forget about removing the `if-else statement`I tested it will give same error caused by casting issues

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy yes you are right my friend, but the user will be notified to when the color of controls like `textbox`, `combobox`, etc will be changed from white (when enabled ) to gray (when disabled)

Comment: @sam If you're getting casting issues then you've still got your control types mixed inside the if/else statements. Check my example carefully, only TextBoxes are inside the TextBox if statement, only ComboBoxes are inside the ComboBox if statement.

Comment: @Equalsk yes you are right My friend I did read it again ..thanks

Answer (score 0):

GB_Product_Entry.Enabled = false;
it will disable all inside in GB_Product_Entry GrpupBox

Comment: I am very sorry for the downvote but this does not _disable_ the child controls (as per the question), they are still enabled - they are just inaccessible while the parent is disabled, much like a control which is on another tabsheet - enabled but not available. The children also do not have the disabled look, and thanks to Windows themes even the caption of the groupbox doesn't look disabled. As far as user interface goes, you need to iterate the controls - and not accidently enable a child that really should have been disabled! Maybe use/write a custom control to handle all of that.