# Is there an easy way to determine if all textbox are not empty and to disable or clear them in C# Windows Form?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, function, textbox, windows-forms-designer

I have a project where in I am required to create a Main Order Windows Form program.

I have three group boxes Customer, Item and Summary.

I need three function wherein:

• 1 function to determine if all textbox in Customer, Items have inputs
• Another function to disable all textbox in Customer
• Another function to clear all textbox in Customer, Item and Summary.

What I think is to create if conditions for every textbox but I think there is another easy way to do this.

My Designer Tab:

[image]

MY Form.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Mail_Order
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    private static double totalAmountDue = 0, totalWeight = 0;

    private static double groundShipping;

    private static int items = 0;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void label3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void label5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void label8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void textBox8_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void label11_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textAddrss.Clear();
        textCustName.Clear();
        textDescription.Clear();
        textPrice.Clear();
        textQuantity.Clear();
        textAmntDue.Clear();
        textCity.Clear();
        textSaleTax.Clear();
        textShipping.Clear();
        textState.Clear();
        textTotalAmntDue.Clear();
        textWeight.Clear();
        textZip.Clear();
        totalAmountDue = 0;
        totalWeight = 0;
    }

    private void groupBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void buttonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //validate input
        if (isNumeric(textQuantity.Text) == false || int.Parse(textQuantity.Text) <= 0)
            errorMessage();

        else if (isNumeric(textWeight.Text) == false || double.Parse(textWeight.Text) <= 0)
            errorMessage();

        else if (isNumeric(textPrice.Text) == false || double.Parse(textPrice.Text) <= 0)
            errorMessage();

        else
            totalAmountDue = totalAmountDue + (double.Parse(textPrice.Text) * double.Parse(textQuantity.Text));
    }

    private void buttonExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Close();
    }

    // identity if numeric
    private bool isNumeric(string s)
    {
        double input;
        return Double.TryParse(s, out input);
    }
    // diplay error for invalid input
    private void errorMessage()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid entry. Please enter a valid amount");
    }
}
}
```

Thanks guys!

Comment: Every form has a `Controls` collection. Iterate through that collection and have an if statement like `if (cntrl is Textbox tb) {tb.DoSomething();}`

Comment: Hi Flydog57 thanks for commenting, is there a link for examples or a more detailed explanation. I am new to Windows forms and I'm not yet familiar with it.

Comment: Sorry, on a phone. For your Btn4 code, do this `for (var ctrl in this.Controls){if (ctrl is TextBox tb) {tb.Clear();}}`. Now, if you have container controls on your page, and they have contained text boxes, then you'll need to dig into those as well

Comment: Hey Flydog57 thanks a lot mate. Also i learned to disable my goupbox from this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42621936/disable-all-controls-within-groupbox

Comment: I addition, you can try the LINQ, `var results = groupBox1.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().ToList(); results.ForEach(x => x.Enabled = false);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could reduce the code and make it cleaner with a bit of refactoring:

```
private bool flag;
private GroupBox[] groups;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    groups = new GroupBox[] { groupBox1, groupBox2, groupBox3 };
}        

// validate if all groupbox have input
private void IsEmpty()
{
    flag = false;            
    for(int i=0; i<groups.Length && !flag; i++)
    {
        foreach(TextBox tb in groups[i].Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
        {
            if (tb.Text.Trim().Length == 0)
            {
                flag = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //clear data
    foreach(GroupBox gb in groups)
    {
        foreach(TextBox tb in gb.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
        {
            tb.Text = " ";
        }
    }
    groupBox1.Enabled = true;
    totalAmountDue = 0; totalWeight = 0; tax = 0; dollarAmountDue = 0;
    groundShipping = 0; shipping = 0; handling = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Flydog57 and AJITH.

I was able to find resources online.

For the first function i use this:

```
// validate if all groupbox have input
    private void IsEmpty()
    {
        flag = false;
        
            foreach (Control cont in groupBox1.Controls)
            {
                if (cont is TextBox)
                {
                    if (((TextBox)cont).Text == "")
                         flag = true;
                }

            }

            foreach (Control cont in groupBox2.Controls)
            {
                if (cont is TextBox)
                {
                    if (((TextBox)cont).Text == "")
                         flag = true;
                }
            }
        
    }
```

Second

```
                    groupBox1.Enabled = false;
```

third

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //clear data

        foreach (Control cont in groupBox1.Controls)
        {
            if (cont is TextBox)
            {
                ((TextBox)cont).Text = " ";
            }
        }

        foreach (Control cont in groupBox2.Controls)
        {
            if (cont is TextBox)
            {
                ((TextBox)cont).Text = " ";
            }
        }

        foreach (Control cont in groupBox3.Controls)
        {
            if (cont is TextBox)
            {
                ((TextBox)cont).Text = " ";
            }
        }

        groupBox1.Enabled = true;

        totalAmountDue = 0; totalWeight = 0; tax = 0; dollarAmountDue = 0;

        groundShipping = 0; shipping = 0; handling = 0;
}
```

Comment: Take a look at what the C# team calls *Pattern Matching*.  With it you can change your `if` statements to `if (cont is TextBox tb)` and then use `tb` in the scope of the `if` without any casting.